# Action Channel in redux-saga calls repeated actions

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I am trying to run several request sequentially with `actionChannel` the issue is that the action and its payload its being retrieved several times (`take`) when I expect only to be retrieved once. This is a reproducible example:

```
function* requestSequentially(action) {
  console.log('action', action); // contains type and payload
  const chan = yield actionChannel(action.type)
  let index = 0;
  while (true) {
    const ac = yield take(chan)
    yield index += 1
    console.log('channel', ac, index);
  }
}
```

The behavior is as follow

- On first dispatch of this action is only logs `action: ...` which is the is before calling the **actionChannel** and never retrieves the action from the channel.
- Next call, outputs `channel, <action> 1`. (previous action queued to the channel).
- On subsequent calls, it starts taking from the channel and logs all previous request like this: (suppose current call is #3)

```
channel <action> 3
channel <action> 2
channel <action> 1
```

If 4th call, well you can imagine it start from 4 then go down to 1.

EDIT:
Saga is exported into rootSaga as:
`takeEvery(SAVE_SEQUENTIALLY, requestSequentially), ...`

and action:
`export const action = payload => ({ type: SAVE_SEQUENTIALLY, payload })`

How can I make actionChannel to only take the action once?

Answer (score 1):

I might be misunderstanding what you are trying to do but to me it seems the problem is the combination of `takeEvery` and the `actionChannel+take`, because both of them are waiting for the same action type.

I think instead of takeEvery you should just fork the `requestSequentially` saga with given type:

```js
yield fork(requestSequentially, SAVE_SEQUENTIALLY)
```

And then use the given type for the actionChannel:

```
function* requestSequentially(type) {
  const chan = yield actionChannel(type)
  let index = 0;
  while (true) {
    const ac = yield take(chan)
    yield index += 1
    console.log('channel', ac, index);
  }
}
```